# HTML table with sticky header

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I need to create a table with overflow horizontal.
The header should be sticky and overflowing too.
Also, 3 first columns should be static.
The table is RTL.
You can see an example here: 
https://www.mouser.co.il/Circuit-Protection/_/N-5g3c
Available only on desktop version.

I don’t have a code to send, my mainly issue is to have the header sticky but also overflowing horizontal.

Thank you,
Eran Greenwald

Comment: Are you tried before? please send a code.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Please kindly post the code you have tried, tell us which part you are having trouble with and we can help from there. Please do post the code you have tried buddy.

Comment: I don’t have a code to send, my mainly issue is to have the header sticky but also overflowing. Thanks

Comment: Tables with fixed headers aren’t exactly a new issue, so you should be able to find lots, if you do some research. If you have problems _after_ you tried a couple of solutions, you can come back here _with_ code then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
th{
  position:sticky;
  top:0px;
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
.table-wrap{
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  height:200px;
  overflow:auto;
}
table{
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrap">
<table>
<tr>
<th>Header</th>
<th>Header</th>
<th>Header</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
<td>Body</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

If header has only one row... its easy:

```
table tr th{
    position:sticky;
    top:0px;
    z-index:150;
}
```

and same for columns but you are not setting top but left/right depends on RTL/LTR setting.

Comment: I will try that, thanks. Does it support all browsers?

Comment: @EranGreenwald all browsers support that and it overflows content inside parent.. you should set table to relative too.. i will edit my answer..

Comment: Thank you, it is working. Is it possible to not set the height like the example link i sent?

Comment: @EranGreenwald if its working then accept it as answer :) and what you mean by that? height of what of that header? or table? specify it more please and i will help

Comment: @EranGreenwald oh you mean that height:200px and overflow: hidden as i did in my example? sure! just delete that two rows and it will still work!